# How to exactly to programmatically copy paste content?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I try to create an automation web browser to post something. but i don't know how to copyy paste. the reason i want to copy paste. it simply copy all text include anchor. example **reddit**. if i put html tag anchor like

```
<a href="#">Example Anchor</a>
```

it would not transcode to [Example Anchor](http://#). but it ouput raw

```
<a href="#">Example Anchor</a>
```

But, if i'm doing copy paste. example in below.

**I'm an [Example Anchor](http://#)**.

It Works.

Answer (score 0):

the main thing why you need a browser that can copy paste behalf you but whatever actually i have not ever make a copy paste automation software but i know about a library called simple html dom for php that can do your work means you can get a text even can download photos using these library . after getting the text you can easily paste that text on whichever site you want but most of site easily can see that you are using a software or script and server will refuse to connect . you can use cURL library to achieve this task . using cURL library you can login into sites and can do your work but of course there are some limits . i do not know whether you know PHP or not but . this is easiest thing you can do without developing a whole browser .

here is the link of simple html dom Documentation https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/

and here is the link of simple html dom library download link : 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/

i hope this will hope you and future reader and googlers

Comment: can u test to publish something like reddit. with copy paste compare to using html tag to post. u will know. your html code will will result raw. it will not transcode to post text. reddit it just example.